# Speeding up COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, which I am looping for a selection of categories. 
Can anyone see a way to speed this query up, as its currently taking far too long to return results.

```
SELECT COUNT(entry_id) AS count_result
FROM (
    SELECT sub.entry_id
    FROM exp_judging AS jud1
    JOIN exp_judging AS jud2 ON jud1.rel_id = jud2.rel_id AND jud2.judge_id = 779 AND jud2.stage_2 IS NULL
    JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud2.rel_id = sub.id 
    WHERE jud1.stage_1 = 1 
    AND sub.member_group = 5
    AND sub.category_id = 10
    GROUP BY jud1.rel_id
    HAVING COUNT(sub.entry_id) >= 3
) AS a
```

Comment: Can you add the explain plan for the query

Comment: use `exmplain {your query}` AND post the result in the question.

Comment: This is too little data to make helping you there possible. Please also include your `table definitions` as well as `index definitions` on those tables as well as the `execution plan` taken for this query, then we might be able to really help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you need the nestes `SELECT` statements there. It looks like instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(entry_id) AS count_result
FROM (
    SELECT sub.entry_id
    ...
) AS a
```

you could simply do

```
SELECT COUNT(sub.entry_id) AS count_result
...
```

This might help the DBMS to optimize your request.